# How to plot multiple group means and the confidence intervals in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, mean, confidence-interval

I have data that looks like this:

```
A  B  C
8  5  2
9  3  1
1  2  3
3  1  2
4  3  1
```

I need to plot the means of each of these along with the confidence intervals using ggplot2. I also want to derive the confidence intervals from the data iteself (eg. using stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl), however I am not sure how I can plot the means for the data from this format.

I tried the following code, but it does not run. I am not sure what needs to go into the y in line 2.

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.78)
ggplot(dat, y = c(dat$A,dat$B,dat$C) + ylim(0,10) + theme_bw()) + 
  stat_summary(geom="bar", fun.y=mean, position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(geom="errorbar", fun.data=mean_cl_normal, position = pd)
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
object 'x' not found 
2: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
object 'x' not found
```

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: You seem to be missing a ) in the ggplot()  .. also please make this a minimal reproducible example by eliminating all the theming etc.    Also what version of ggplot2 are you on?

Comment: @Elin: I have made the updates. I am using ggplot2 2.1.0

Comment: `fun.data = "mean_cl_boot"` or "mean_cl_normal", "mean_cl" isn't a function recognized by ggplot and you gotta quote it

Comment: @NathanDay Neither of it works. I get the same error

Comment: what does your ggplot call look like with just `+geom_point()` forgetting about the `stat_summary()` layers

Comment: But the stat summary layers have the mean function and given that it is the man and CI I'm interested in plotting, I don't know how it would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like David said, you need long format first, but you should be able to use `fun.data = "mean_cl_normal"` or plug in various others just fine like this:

```
library(tidyr); library(ggplot2)
dat <- gather(dat) # gather to long form

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = key, y = value)) +
    geom_point(size = 4, alpha = .5) + # always plot the raw data
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_normal", geom = "crossbar") +
    labs(title = "95% Mean Confidence Intervals")
```

[image]

If you want to build the same intervals manually all you need are `lm` and `confint` to get the information you are after:

```
mod <- lm(value ~ 0 + key, data = dat)
ci <- confint(mod)
```

Comment: Very nice solution Nathan! 
Notice how the arguments in `mean_cl_normal` have to have a match.  The error "object 'x' not found" means that there was no variable "x" for ggplot to evaluate.  Nathan's code above shows ggplot that is `x = key` and `y = value` and so it can evaluate it in  `stat_summary`.

Comment: thanks David, stat_summary's default `fun.data` is "mean_se", so you could just call `stat_summary(group = something appropriate, geom = "errorbar")` if you wanted to replicate your example without the the ddply. super nice for quick viz

Answer (score 7):

Your data isn't in long format, meaning that it should look like this:

```
thing<-data.frame(Group=factor(rep(c("A","B","C"),5)),
                  Y = c(8,9,1,3,4, 
                        5,3,2,1,3,
                        2,1,3,2,1)
                  )
```

You can use a function like `melt()` to help with getting the data formatted in the `reshape2` package.

Once you have that, you also have to calculate the means and SEs for your data (by hand prior to `ggplot` or by the correct expressions within `stat_summary` in `ggplot`).  You may have copied/pasted from an example because the functions that you're using (eg, `mean_cl_normal`) are possibly undefined.

Let's do it by hand then.

```
library(plyr)

cdata <- ddply(thing, "Group", summarise,
               N    = length(Y),
               mean = mean(Y),
               sd   = sd(Y),
               se   = sd / sqrt(N)
)
cdata

#Group N mean       sd       se
#1     A 5  4.0 2.236068 1.000000
#2     B 5  3.8 3.033150 1.356466
#3     C 5  1.8 1.788854 0.800000
```

Now you can use `ggplot`.

```
pd <- position_dodge(0.78)

ggplot(cdata, aes(x=Group, y = mean, group = Group)) +
   #draws the means
      geom_point(position=pd) +
   #draws the CI error bars
      geom_errorbar(data=cdata, aes(ymin=mean-2*se, ymax=mean+2*se, 
      color=Group), width=.1, position=pd)
```

This gives the attached plot.

[image: Mean and CI Plot]